# How to run two spark job in EMR cluster?

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr

I've a realtime spark job which runs in EMR cluster and I've another batch job which runs in another EMR cluster and this job is triggered at specific time.
How to run both these jobs in one EMR cluster ?

Any suggestions.

Comment: When I last looked at EMR it was not meant or long running processes such as real-time AMAZON told me.  Interesting.

Comment: yes it supports for real-time process.

Comment: Different to what they told me...interesting

Answer (score 3):

If the steps in both the EMR are not dependent on each other, then you can use the feature called `Concurrency` in the EMR to solve your use case. This feature simply means that you can run more than 1 step in parallel at a time.

This feature is there from the EMR version **5.28.0**. If you are using the older version than this then you can not use this feature.

While launching the EMR from the AWS console, this feature is termed as **'Concurrency'** in the UI. you can choose any number between 1 to 256.

If you are launching the EMR from the AWS CLI, then this feature is termed as **'StepConcurrencyLevel'**.

You can read more about this at [multiple steps now in EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/amazon-emr-now-allows-you-to-run-multiple-steps-in-parallel-cancel-running-steps-and-integrate-with-aws-step-functions/)   and [AWS CLI details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/APIReference/API_RunJobFlow.html#EMR-RunJobFlow-request-StepConcurrencyLevel)